# How to uninstall plex from ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, dpkg

I am finding it impossible to completely remove plex from my Ubuntu system, i get the following error:

```
davewold@ubuntuhome:~$ sudo aptitude purge plexmediaserver
[sudo] password for davewold: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
Ignoring unknown parameter "announce version"
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  libavahi-core7{u} libavahi-gobject0{u} plexmediaserver{p} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 409 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 204286 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libavahi-gobject0:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
(Reading database ... 204272 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing plexmediaserver (0.9.11.7.803-87d0708-debian) ...
Plex Media Server is not running (no process found)...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: thats after using all the official commands for removal

Comment: any luck with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try to force the removal with `sudo aptitude -f purge plexmediaserver` If it doesn't work, try these commands:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all plexmediaserver
```

Comment: i tried that command and this is the result, i'm lost at the moment

Comment: Removing plexmediaserver (0.9.11.7.803-87d0708-debian) ...
Plex Media Server is not running (no process found)...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

Comment: I edited the answer, try now.

Comment: no luck i get this Plex Media Server is not running (no process found)...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver

Comment: Try now. I made a edit.

Comment: You might need also to `sudo userdel plex`

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but it helped me sometimes.

Reinstall the package, then try `sudo apt-get --purge remove <package>`.

Also make sure no process is running, related to this package.

If this doesn't work then do it the hard way..

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.* /tmp/
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package>
```

Comment: won't let me reinstall, i'm going around in circles with this, i'm nearly at stage of reinstalling ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /etc/init.d/
```

get rid of the plex init entry

```
sudo mv plexmediaserver plexmediaserver.dead
```

remove it from update-rc

```
sudo update-rc.d -f plexmediaserver remove
```

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove -f plexmediaserver
```

delete the init.d entry

```
sudo rm -rf plexmediaserver.dead
```