# How to resolve : dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

Tags: dpkg

How to resolve :

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  plexmediaserver
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/127 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 252173 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../plexmediaserver_0.9.12.1.1079-b655370-debian_amd64.deb ...
Killing Plex Media Server: done
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Killing Plex Media Server: done
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/plexmediaserver_0.9.12.1.1079-b655370-debian_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/plexmediaserver_0.9.12.1.1079-b655370-debian_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: i guess the package was not downloaded.

Comment: A similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/599340/ .