# Unable to remove plexmedia server from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, plex

I am unable to remove Plexmedia server from Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64-bit.
Whenever I try to remove it via apt-get or dpkg -r, I am getting following error message.

```
happy@happy-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg --purge plexmediaserver
    (Reading database ... 191869 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing plexmediaserver (0.9.11.7.803-87d0708-debian) ...
    update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
    dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--purge):
     subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     plexmediaserver
```

I have tried searching on google, but could not find a solution.

Thanks for your time and please let me know if any more information is required from my side!

Comment: Have you tried `-f` to force? Give me a comment with @A.B.

Comment: Similar questions are http://askubuntu.com/questions/599340/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/621147/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq -P plexmediaserver
```

If that does not work, remove the files by hand:

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/plexmediaserver /tmp
```

and again:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq -P plexmediaserver
```

Comment: Thanks, moving the plexmediaserver from init.d manually and then executing the dpkg worked.

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote answers at the moment, so marking it. Thanks for the solution :)