# Apport is preventing me from upgrading my system, how do I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, package-management, upgrade

When I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` I get the following error

```
(Reading database ... 135000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15_all.deb ...
Failed to stop apport-forward.socket: Unit apport-forward.socket not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop apport-forward.socket: Unit apport-forward.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read apport-forward.socket
Failed to get unit file state for apport-forward.socket: No such file or directory
apport-forward.socket is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to remove the package (uninstall it) that is causing the problem, here some examples:

- [How to remove/install a package that is not fully installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/438365)
- [How to uninstall plex from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599340/how-to-uninstall-plex-from-ubuntu) (You're not having problems with plex, but the error message is the same, so it could be a good idea to have a look at it).

After removing the package that is causing the problem, you can update your system and finally re-install the package if required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually just commented out the problem lines in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm` , uninstalled apport, reinstalled apport, then upgraded. BOOM. problem fixed!